# Is there a way to create ab new key chnage key to value of an object and replace the key with custom name dynamically?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

this =>>>>>
{1: "Baroque", 2: "Glitch Pop ", 3: "Nu Jazz", 4: "Drumfunk", 5: "Bitpop", 6: "Latin Pop", 7: "Carnatic"}

to this ==>>>>

[{id: 1 name: "Baroque"}, {id: 2, name: "Glitch Pop "}, {id:3 name: "Nu Jazz"}, {id:4 name: "Drumfunk"}, {id: 5 name:"Bitpop"}, {id: 6 name: "Latin Pop"}, {id: 7 name: "Carnatic"}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could map the entries of the object by destructuring the key/value pairs to the wanted variables and take short hand proerties for new objects.

```js
var data = { 1: "Baroque", 2: "Glitch Pop ", 3: "Nu Jazz", 4: "Drumfunk", 5: "Bitpop", 6: "Latin Pop", 7: "Carnatic" },
    result = Object.entries(data).map(([id, name]) => ({ id, name }));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   var obj = {1: "Baroque", 2: "Glitch Pop ", 3: "Nu Jazz", 4: "Drumfunk", 5: 
    "Bitpop", 6: "Latin Pop", 7: "Carnatic"}
    var result = Object.keys(obj).map((key) => [Number(key), obj[key]]);
    let output=[]
     result.forEach((element)=>{
        output.push({
            "id":element[0],
            "name":element[1]
        })
     })
     console.log('output',output);
```

you will get the object in desired format

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in functional programming way as below, with one line statement!

```
 Object.keys(source).map(key => ({id: key, name : source[key]}))
```

Find the below snippet for a quick view of the result

```js
const source =  {1: "Baroque", 2: "Glitch Pop ", 3: "Nu Jazz", 4: "Drumfunk", 5: "Bitpop", 6: "Latin Pop", 7: "Carnatic"};
const result =  Object.keys(source).map(key => ({id: key, name : source[key]}))



console.log(result)
```

Comment: it does not look like the wanted result with `id` and `name` as properties ...